# HttpURLConnection returns 200 always in mockito

Tags: java, junit, powermockito

I'm running a test with a `HttpURLConnection`. But I wanted to return 204 as the response code.

```
@Test
public void should_return_result_with_success_data() throws Exception {
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = PowerMockito.mock(HttpURLConnection.class);
    URL finalUrl = PowerMockito.mock(URL.class);

    PowerMockito.whenNew(URL.class).withArguments("http://sample.com").thenReturn(finalUrl);
    PowerMockito.when(finalUrl.openConnection()).thenReturn(urlConnection);
    PowerMockito.when(urlConnection.getResponseCode()).thenReturn(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_NO_CONTENT);

    task.call();
}
```

**Implementation**

```
@Override
public EventResult call() throws Exception {
    url = url.concat(URLEncoder.encode(data, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()));

    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://sample.com").openConnection();
    connection.setConnectTimeout(connectionTimeout);
    connection.setReadTimeout(readTimeout);

    EventResult eventResult = new EventResult();
    eventResult.setHttpStatusCode(connection.getResponseCode());

    if (connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_NO_CONTENT) {
        return eventResult;
    } else {
        eventResult = JsonPojoConverter.getEventResult(IOUtils.toString(connection.getErrorStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()));
    }
    return eventResult;
}
```

Why it returns 200 response code always. Are there any workaround to get 204 returned?

Comment: how are you injecting the mocked HttpURLConnection in your task object ???

Comment: Updated the question. I'm not injecting the connection. It's a local variable.

Comment: So , the task.call() is making actual HttpURLConnection and not using your mocked object. One approach have constructor of task class to take  URLConnection as arguement. Store it as class level variable and use it to make the call. You will need to refractor your code to be able to test it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

whenever we mock method local instantiation using whenNew, we have to add the classname of the method which is instantiating in prepareForTest.

If the className of the method call is MyTask then add it in prepareForTest as below.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({MyTask.class})
public class MyTaskTest {

}
```

Comment: This was what I exactly did to fix my problem. Thanks